# Share a PDF in ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, jspdf

I want to share a pdf from my ionic app that I have created using jsPDF. How can I use it along with SocialSharing plug-in?

```
doc.save("resume.pdf")
```

This directly downloads the pdf and take me to the screen where I can't do anything.

```
 //share(message, subject, file, url)
 this.socialSharing.share("Test", null, doc.save("resume.pdf"), null);
```

this also won't work. I am new to ionic and angular.

Update: I studied and followed [this article](https://gonehybrid.com/how-to-create-and-display-a-pdf-file-in-your-ionic-app/) which talks about making a pdf with `pdfmake` in the ionic app, but I still can't figure out how to share the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

var blob = doc.output('blob', {type: 'application/pdf'});
let pdfUrl = {pdfUrl: URL.createObjectURL(blob)};

if (this.file.checkFile(this.file.cacheDirectory, "myresume.pdf")) 
{
 this.file.writeExistingFile(this.file.cacheDirectory, "myresume.pdf",blob)
         .then(() => console.log('overwrite done'))
         .catch(err => console.log(err +' old copies not removed'));
} else{
    this.file.writeFile(this.file.cacheDirectory, "myresume.pdf", blob, true)
        .then(_ => console.log('write successful'))
        .catch(err => console.log(err+ " write failed"));
}
```

For sharing it,

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';
export class ResumeView {
       pdfUrl : String;
       constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
                    public navParams: NavParams,
                    private socialSharing: SocialSharing,
                    private file: File
                   ) 
       {
           this.pdfUrl = this.navParams.get('pdfUrl'); 
       }
       regularShare(){
           this.socialSharing.share("test", null, this.file.cacheDirectory + filename, null)
        }
```